# IntelliJ change markers reflecting local changes instead of VCS changes?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, intellij-13

One feature I really like about IntelliJ is the change markers displayed in the gutter of a file under version control.

However, my current system seems to have gotten itself into a state where that area now shows only *local* changes, not changes with respect to git. I can't find the setting to switch it back.

Is anyone aware of how to do this? I'm using IntelliJ 13.1 community edition on a Mac.

Changes are shown in the project navigation window, so I know it's a settings issue, not that the file isn't being recognized as under version control.

Comment: Have you figured that out? I have 14 EAP and the change markers disappeared completely even though I have the project under git control

Comment: It was due to editing symbolic link...

Comment: I have the opposite problem, I WANT to show change markers for local changes but can't figure out how to do it. Would you mind taking a look at this, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708369/can-intellij-idea-show-change-markers-for-local-changes