# Can IntelliJ IDEA show change markers for local changes?

Tags: intellij-idea

One of the features I love in Visual Studio is that it notes, with color-coded bars in the left margin, which lines I've changed in the program I'm editing.

Is it possible to get something similar in IntelliJ IDEA?

I'm aware that it has a "change markers" feature for files that are under version control, but that's not applicable for me. I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769393/intellij-change-markers-reflecting-local-changes-instead-of-vcs-changes) which seems to imply that it should be possible, although that guy had the opposite problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gutter marks that you are asking about only appear when you are using a VCS with the project.

IDEA will track local history, but does not show the changes in the gutter (most likely because this local history is temporary and is overwritten when the cache is invalidated or when an upgrade is done).

To view the completely history, right click on the file in the Project view, and under Local History select Show History:

[image: history]

The above image is taken from the [online documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-local-history-of-a-file-or-folder.html), where it describes the Local History feature:

> This section describes how to use Local History, which is your
>   personal real-time version control system. Local History is
>   independent of external version control systems and works with the
>   directories of your project even when they are not under any VCS
>   control.

If you want local history changes to be shown in the gutter, you can raise this as a feature request at the [bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's quite what I'm looking for. I'd like to see the changes marked automatically in the left margin of the editor window as I'm working on editing the source file. This link http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-change-markers-to-view-and-navigate-through-changes-in-the-editor.html shows the "change markers" that are possible (default?) for editing a file under version control. I'd like the same, or something similar, despite not using any version control system.

Comment: OK, thanks for the edit of your answer. If I don't get any other answers in a day or two I'll submit a feature request, as you suggest, and accept your answer.

Comment: Here's my feature request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129763 It is possible to vote for issues by clicking on the thumbs-up button, so please vote for my request everyone!